# How to convert String into DateTime Format in MySql/PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have table having few number of columns wherein one column is for Execution number (`exe_number`) which stores the data in varchar(100).

```
select*from exedetails;
+------------+------------+------------+-------------+
| exe_number | pass_count | fail_count | error_count |
+------------+------------+------------+-------------+
| 02Aug_E1   |         98 |          9 |           0 |
| 31Jul_E1   |         94 |          8 |           1 |
| 30Jul_E2   |         76 |          9 |           3 |
| 01Aug_E2   |         98 |          7 |           0 |
| 02Aug_E2   |         76 |          8 |           2 |
| 30Jul_E1   |         98 |         12 |           9 |
| 31Jul_E2   |         91 |          6 |           1 |
| 01Aug_E1   |         67 |         14 |           2 |
+------------+------------+------------+-------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

describe exedetails;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| exe_number  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pass_count  | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| fail_count  | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| error_count | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here `30/31/01/02` are a date, `Aug/Jul` is a month and `E1/E2` is Execution iteration (This is for my simplicity).

Lets consider present date is

> '02 August 2022'

So I want to write a query in such a way that all records starting with

> 02Aug_

should be at the top of table.
Means It should get arranged according to **date** so that present day record should be at the top.

Query I wrote for this is not giving desired result:

```
select exe_number from exedetails order by exe_number desc;
+------------+
| exe_number |
+------------+
| 31Jul_E2   |
| 31Jul_E1   |
| 30Jul_E2   |
| 30Jul_E1   |
| 02Aug_E2   |
| 02Aug_E1   |
| 01Aug_E2   |
| 01Aug_E1   |
+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select exe_number from exedetails order by exe_number asc;
+------------+
| exe_number |
+------------+
| 01Aug_E1   |
| 01Aug_E2   |
| 02Aug_E1   |
| 02Aug_E2   |
| 30Jul_E1   |
| 30Jul_E2   |
| 31Jul_E1   |
| 31Jul_E2   |
+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Expected Result :**

```
+------------+
| exe_number |
+------------+
| 02Aug_E1   |
| 02Aug_E2   |
| 01Aug_E1   |
| 01Aug_E2   |
| 31Jul_E1   |
| 31Jul_E2   |
| 30Jul_E1   |
| 30Jul_E2   |
+------------+
```

Is there any way in MySQL/PostgreSQL by which I can get my desired solution?

Comment: Are you using postgres or mysql?

Comment: Like order should be like 22Aug_E1 then 22Aug_E2 then 21Aug_E1 then 21Aug_E2 then 20Aug_E1 then 20Aug_E2

Comment: Does shown sample data is the value of the column in one row, or these are values from 6 separate rows?

Comment: But it's a **single** value - how can you have multiple rows sorted with a single value? Do you also want to split the elements of each column into multiple rows?

Comment: @Akina these sample data belongs to one column only.....

I need to write a query in such manner so that these records should get arranged as per date in ascending or descending order.

like

22Aug_E1
22Aug_E2
21Aug_E1
21Aug_E2
20Aug_E1
20Aug_E2

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  These all records are present in one column only. With a query I wrote , records get arranged as per number like 22,21,20,19 etc.
But I want them to arrange as per 22Aug,21Aug,20Aug,19Aug etc.
In short they should get arranged as per date format.

Comment: *these sample data belongs to one column only* To avoid the ambiguity provide this sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts please. Also provide desired output for this data (as textual table). And specify one definite DBMS, including its precise version.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  kindly see the image.....Hopefully you will understand

Comment: @Akina kindly see the image.....Hopefully you will understand

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert the "date part" to a proper `date` value, then you can sort by it:

```
select *
from exedetails
order by to_date(left(exe_number, 5), 'ddmon') desc, 
         right(exe_number, 2)
```

Note that `to_date()` working with a month *name* depends on your locale settings and the values in the column.

[Online example for Postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0f1393355de2eb2bddcebf03ff717c99)

Comment: Thank you so much...it is working
Is it possible to arrange E1/E2/E3 along with date?
because they are not arranged properly

Comment: @TheTester they are included in the `order by` so I don't know what you mean with "arrange".